# Began accidentally deleting Bot Framework Account

Tags: botframework

So, I clicked the Account page on my developer account from the dev.botframework.com dashboard, and that page is apparently the delete account action? I thought it was just wanting me to confirm my email and then I read it after submitting and tried to stop it, but when I log out and back in the bots are missing from that dashboard, but my apps are still listed https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList and are still running in Azure. Is there any ability to recover the missing bots linking to Azure or what should I do? Everything looks to still be working - is that dashboard even required?

Comment: Can you still see and/or access your bots in https://portal.azure.com? The dev.botframework.com dashboard has been in the process of being deprecated, and the Azure portal is now the main place for seeing, altering and hosting bots.

Comment: I can, that's the feeling I was getting as well. When I started building my bot I had to migrate my bots from botframework.com to azure's bot channel registry.

Comment: If your bots are still on the portal, you're good to go. Mourn your dev.botframework.com list, but get used to Azure Portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bot Framework Portal was created way back in the preview version of the Bot Framework, as a way to develop and manage bots. As of Dec 2017, bot are created and managed in the Azure Portal (which makes since, as the bots  run in Azure). MOST bots were required to migrate to Azure (there are a few that do not require it, but heavily hint you should). Additionally, any bots created after Dec 2017 were automatically created in Azure anyway.

That being said, all the functionality of the Bot Framework Developer Portal is maintained on Azure. Adding channels, changing the endpoint, adding admin, etc, can be done in the settings of the Azure Bot resource. If your bots can be found in the Azure Portal, and are still listed in Apps.Dev.Microsoft.Com, then you're good to go, even if you accidentally delete your Bot Framework Developer Portal.

Comment: This is probably a longshot - but I'm trying to update the Bots Channel Registration Messaging Endpoint, but it is erroring when doing so. The error the save call is encountering is `error: {code: "InvalidBotData", message: ": OwnerIds is required for non-ABS bots. "}` - is this related to my half-deleted account or is there somewhere I could remedy this?

Comment: Let me run this past a coworker, but I believe this DOES have to do with the half deleted account. a non-ABS bot is a non-migrated bot, the state bots were allowed to be in in early v3 and back. Later in the v3 lifecycle, bots were required to be considered 'Azure Bot Service' bots and creating a new one routed users straight to Azure Portal. I'm not 100% sure how to correct your issue here, but you can email me at v-jewail@microsoft.com and I'll see what we can do.

Comment: I was able to just delete the old bot that wouldn't let me change the endpoint, and recreate it and haven't had any issues updating the endpoint. That was my staging/test bot, so didn't really hurt to delete/recreate. I don't think I'll need to do that on my production one, but if I do, I think delete/create fixes this issue.

Comment: Glad it worked, but if it happens again, please feel free to email me.